# how to ensure that a UNIX script runs continuously?

Tags: shell, unix

I have written the following script for running a Java class:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set this to the directory where the JDK is installed
JAVA_HOME=/opt/weblogic-9.2mp1/java1.5

# Set this to the path to the JAR file containing the JMS classes
# (for example, the path to the weblogic.jar file)
JMS_JAR=/opt/weblogic-9.2mp1/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar

# Specify the name of the <ServerNode> node in ASC
SERVER_NODE_NAME=TDCPublisher

# If you have custom save beans and load beans in your own JAR file,
# append your JAR file to this variable.
CLASSPATH=$JMS_JAR:$JAR_DIR/ClfyCore.jar:$JAR_DIR/awsi.jar:$JAR_DIR/acfglib.jar:$JAR_DIR/jaxen-1.1-beta-9.jar:$JAR_DIR/Amdocs
Aif.jar:$JAR_DIR/AmdocsProcMgrBase.jar:$JAR_DIR/AmdocsSvcCommon.jar:/apps/fasigw/test/fasigwApp/custom/FASIGWLink.jar
export CLASSPATH

# Set the path for accessing the JDK directory
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

checkJDK()
{
  if [ ! -f $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ]; then
    echo "Error: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java not found."
    echo "Please edit this script so that the JAVA_HOME variable"
    echo "points to the root directory of your JDK installation."
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}

checkClassPath()
{
  if [ ! -f $JAR_DIR/ClfyCore.jar ]; then
    echo "Error: $JAR_DIR/ClfyCore.jar not found."
    echo "Please edit this script so that the JAR_DIR variable"
    echo "points to the directory where ClfyCore.jar and the other"
    echo "ClarifyCRM JAR files are located."
  return 1
  fi
  return 0
}

main()
{
  checkJDK
      if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        return 1
      fi
  checkClassPath
      if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        return 1
      fi


$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/apps/fasigw/test/AmdocsCRM7.5/AmdocsCRMApplication/conf/auth.conf  -
cp ${CLASSPATH} com.clarify.daevtpub.ClarifyEventProcessor sa cleartest -pl ${SERVER_NODE_NAME} -ShowStatus -Debug -OutFile /
apps/fasigw/test/logs/DataChangeLog.log

  return 0
}

main $*
```

But the problem faced is - once I exit from the server and login again, though I can see the process is running using the command **ps -ef**,the class is not being executed. I need to manually start running the scrip again. How to avoid this and ensure that the script is continuously running in background? The script name is startEventProcessor and I execute the following command to run the script:

```
./startEventProcessor &
```

Comment: There is no need to explicitly check `$?`.  Just write: `if ! checkJDK; then return 1; fi`  Also, even though this script does not use the arguments, you should get in the habit of quoting properly and use: `main "$@"` instead of `main $*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nohup](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nohup/):

```
nohup ./startEventProcessor &
```